# Deriving the number density of electrons distributed by bi-kappa distribution in plasmas

Tags: electrons, plasma-physics

Can anyone explain the derivation of the number density of electrons distributed by the following bi-kappa distribution function commonly observed in space plasmas:
\begin{equation}
f_e(V_\perp,V_\parallel)=A_{\kappa}\left(1+\frac{B_\kappa}{(\kappa-\frac{3}{2})}\right)^{-\kappa-1}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
A_{\kappa}=\Biggl[\frac{1}{\pi(\kappa-\frac{3}{2})}\Biggr]^{3/2}\frac{n_0\Gamma(\kappa+1)}{V_{T\perp}^2V_{T\parallel}\Gamma(\kappa-\frac{1}{2})},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
B_{\kappa}=\left[\left(\frac{V_\parallel-v_{0\parallel}}{V_{T\parallel}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{V_\perp-v_{0\perp}}{V_{T\perp}}\right)^2\right],
\end{equation}
$\Gamma$ is the Riemann gamma function, $n_0$ is the number density of electrons, $V_{T\parallel}$ ($V_{T\perp}$) is the most probable (parallel) perpendicular electron velocity, $v_{0\parallel}$ ($v_{0\perp}$) is the drift velocity of electrons in (parallel) perpendicular direction.

Comment: Is not this distribution a generalization of Boltzmann-Gibbs statistics for systems that are in a stationary state but out of thermal equilibrium?

Comment: @ManpreetSingh - See https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019ApJS..243....8W/abstract and references therein for details on how to derive the parameters of a bi-kappa VDF.

Comment: @Mass - Plasmas in space are inherently unstable and virtually never in equilibrium, either thermal or thermodynamic.  That is, you do not observe Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution functions in space plasmas.

Comment: @honeste_vivere, this is the same distribution function given in the above paper you shared. I am trying to derive the number density of electrons using the above distribution function. It seems more complicated to derive the number density using the above distribution function.'

Comment: @ManpreetSingh - What do you mean by derive?  Do you mean integrate $f_{e}\left( V_{\perp}, V_{\parallel} \right)$ over all $V_{\perp}$ and $V_{\parallel}$ to get the zeroth velocity moment?